# XPath1.0: Convert UTC Seconds to datetime format string

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

Is there a way of converting UTC seconds to a String with this format: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: Side note: You *ought* to use `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` as a datetime format.

Comment: Because it's universally recognizable, unambiguous and it sorts properly. For a *technical* representation of a date (i.e. storage and processing) every alternative representation is inferior to this one. For a purely *visual* representation, other formats (i.e. what users commonly expect) are ok. Relevant XKCD http://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: @Tomalak I agree with you. In this case, it's purely visualisation. For sorting etc yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss is a better format indeed.

Comment: `2014-07-11` is unabmiguously the 11th of July 2014, but some people could mistake `11/07/2014` for the 7th of November instead.  `dd/mm/yyyy` is fine if you know all your readers are Europeans but if you have a mix of UK and US readers then `yyyy-mm-dd` is safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively in XPath 1.0, you'd need to use an appropriate extension function.  How (indeed whether) you can do this depends what library/language/tool you're using to evaluate the XPath expressions.

Comment: I only have native XPath 1.0. I would be looking for a calculation then.